# Searchkick reindexing not picking up queued changes

Tags: searchkick

I'm following along with the [Queuing section of the README](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#queuing) which seems to work fine until I begin a re-index operation. I'm noticing that I don't seem to get new changes that have happened after the re-index is started. For example if I have a model Product:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick callbacks: :queue
end
```

1. `Product.reindex(mode: :async)`

   - While the index is still reindexing:

     1. `new_product = Product.create`
     2. `Searchkick::ProcessQueueJob.perform_now(class_name: "Product")`
2. new_product is not included in the new index

What is the best way to handle this so that new_product will be included in the new index?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t t need to set `Product.reindex(mode: :async)`
when you use `callbacks: :queue`.

Jobs are added to a queue named `searchkick` in your `sidekiq` server
You need to configure also redis like:

```
 config_redis = { host: ENV.fetch('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), port: ENV.fetch('REDIS_PORT', 6380) }
 Searchkick.redis = Redis.new(config_redis)
```

then in your service or where you usually trigger the db modification, after that you can call the reindex.

```
 Searchkick::ProcessQueueJob.perform_later(class_name: "<your model name>")
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't exactly answer my question. I've found a diagram to better illustrate my question: https://ankane.org/introducing-searchkick-pro#reliable-reindexing

Basically I'd like to know if there's a recommended or even built-in method to allow for reliable reindexing.